# How to check isapi and CGI filters are installed

Tags: c#, iis

Is there any way to check isapi and CGI filters are installed or not. I want a C# program that check these filters are installed or not. Is there any registry check exists? Or any other way to check.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is certainly available in the `ServerManager` module with PowerShell (PSH, on Server 2008 R2):

```
get-WindowsFeature Web-CGI,Web-IS* | ft -auto displayname,name.installed
```

results in, on a server here:

```
DisplayName      Name             Installed
-----------      ----             ---------
CGI              Web-CGI              False
ISAPI Extensions Web-ISAPI-Ext        False
ISAPI Filters    Web-ISAPI-Filter     False
```

Which means using a PSH [`Runspace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace%28VS.85%29.aspx) and the PSH runtime would be a way to get this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WMI instrumentations: [check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689464%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). You can start from here for the specific question [about isapi filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347549%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).